# Placing my ActionBar at the bottom

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

I followed a tutorial on getting actionbars in my app.  But even when I put `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` in my Manifest file it still keeps it at the top.  Anyone has any ideas on what to do with this code?

**XML:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#f0f0f0" 
android:baselineAligned="false">

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/myFragments"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Manifest File:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.alotoftesting"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Which SDK version are you running this on? I see your target is 15 and your minimum is 11.

Comment: I've never heard of being able to move the action bar. If you figure it out please post the answer here.

Comment: How many menu items do you have in your ActionBar? The `splitActionBarWhenNarrow` option basically allows overflow into a second, "split" action bar on the bottom if your menu items won't fit at the top. If all your menu items fit at the top you won't see the split layout.

Comment: @Quinma I ran it on my honeycomb emulator.

Comment: Dang is there really no way to get this on the bottom?

Comment: @twaddington Oh thats what it means.  I had the wrong idea on this.  Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: No problem. It violates the Android Design patterns to use a bottom tab bar. As others have said, I'd advise against it: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The google default action bar does not in any case appear on the bottom.  As it seems others have mentioned, `splitActionBarWhenNarrow` only puts a subset of your `ActionBar` (like tabs, etc) on the bottom of the screen when the device is narrow.  Unfortunately, if you want to implement an ActionBar like interface on the bottom of the screen, you'll have to implement it yourself ([a quick search finds this example](http://android-ed.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-actionbar-at-bottom-of-screen.html)), as I haven't seen any Libraries to do this for you.

In all, though, I would recommend against it, as it violates the [Seamlessness design principle](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/seamlessness.html) in the design documents by breaking user expectations of where ActionBar type controls will be - An android user is ideally used to doing things a certain way, and you would need a pretty compelling reason to break that expectation.

Comment: `splitActionBarWhenNarrow` move the action items (defined in a menu xml), not tabs to the bottom

Comment: As a designer & developer I have to disagree with you view in the last paragraph. While yes it would break Android UI guidelines, but who is to say that that is the only way to design the UI for an app. Guidelines help ensure that most of Android apps are recognizable, reducing the learning curve for users. But if you know what you're doing you could push the envelope a bit and experiment, as long as you dont hinder user experience that is.

Comment: @AlexVPerl as I said, your reasons should be compelling to break expectations - I can't rule out that there's a use case where having that bar there would make the app better.  It should not be done lightly, however.  Like you said, you should make sure you know what you're doing when you deviate from the guidelines

Comment: Actually Droid Edit, or any text editor I know places UI controls such as undo at the bottom. And navigation tabs at top

Answer (score 7):

According to this comment:

> How many menu items do you have in your ActionBar? The
>   splitActionBarWhenNarrow option basically allows overflow into a
>   second, "split" action bar on the bottom if your menu items won't fit
>   at the top. If all your menu items fit at the top you won't see the
>   split layout.

If you would like to have a custom bottom toolbar, please check my answer to this question (added below):

> ## Creating custom bottom toolbar
>
> I've already created a simple app which should demonstrate you how to
>   begin
>
> [image] [image]
>
> #### Creating a custom ViewGroup
>
> Here's my `activity_main.xml` layout file:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <RelativeLayout
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:padding="0dp"
>     tools:context="com.example.piotr.myapplication.MainActivity">
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:id="@+id/show_pdf"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="40dp"
>         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>         android:background="@color/primary_material_light"
>         android:orientation="horizontal">
>
>         <ImageButton
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight="1"
>             android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_cut_mtrl_alpha"/>
>
>         <ImageButton
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight="1"
>             android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha"/>
>
>         <ImageButton
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight="1"
>             android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_selectall_mtrl_alpha"/>
>
>         <ImageButton
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight="1"
>             android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_paste_mtrl_am_alpha"/>
>
>         <ImageButton
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight="1"
>             android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha"/>
>
>         <ImageButton
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight="1"
>             android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_selectall_mtrl_alpha"/>
>
>         <ImageButton
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_weight="1"
>             android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha"/>
>     </LinearLayout>
>
>     <EditText
>         android:id="@+id/editText"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>         android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
>         android:ems="10"
>         android:inputType="textPersonName"
>         android:text="Name"/>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```
>
> As you can see my parent `ViewGroup` is `RelativeLayout`, which simply
>   allows me to create a view at the bottom of screen.
>
> Notice that I set layout padding to zero (I think: setting layout
>   margin to zero here is not necessary, the same effect). If you'd
>   change it, the toolbar won't use full width and it won't stick with
>   bottom of the screen.
>
> Then I added a Linear Layout with hardcoded height which is:
>
> ```
>           android:layout_height="40dp"
> ```
>
> I wanted it, that my bottom toolbar would take full available width so
>   I set it as `match_parent`.
>
> Next, I added some `ImageButton` views with images from Android
>   library.
>
> There you have two possibilities:
>
> - if you really want to have a toolbar like in above example just remove in every `ImageButton` view this line:
>
>   ```
>         android:layout_weight="1"
>   ```
>
> After removing weights and some buttons you would get a view pretty
>   similar to expected:
>
> [image]
>
> - if you want to take the full width and make every button with the same size use in your project `weight` as in this mine example.
>
> Now let's go to my **AndroidManifest.xml**
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <manifest package="com.example.piotr.myapplication"
>           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>
>     <application
>         android:allowBackup="true"
>         android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>         android:label="@string/app_name"
>         android:supportsRtl="true"
>         android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
>         <activity
>             android:name=".MainActivity"
>             android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
>             <intent-filter>
>                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
>
>                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
>             </intent-filter>
>         </activity>
>     </application>
> </manifest>
> ```
>
> In that file I'd added as you can see only one additional line:
>
> ```
>          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
> ```
>
> to make sure that device keyboard won't hide my custom bottom toolbar.
>
> From: [How to add a bottom menu to Android activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34311601/how-to-add-a-bottom-menu-to-android-activity/34422850#34422850)

I think in that way you can also put tabs at the bottom if needed.

If you have any question please free to ask.

Hope it help