# Tab bar app in Android 4.0

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-webview, android-tabs

I am going to develop a android app in Android 4.0 like the below image.

[image: ActionBar with Tab]

I have to create these tabs dynamically, that dynamically call addTab() method and create tab bar dynamically. Is the **ActionBarWithTab** right for my requirement.?Guide me to the right way. Please provide tutorials.

EDIT 1: I need to load webview in the separate tab bar created in the ActionBar.

EIDT 2: For creating the tab bar using the TabHost, first i have created the ViewGroup ffor TabHost and added the tab bar items like the below code. In the tab bar items I have created the layout, inside the layout a webview and loaded the dynamic url into the tab bar item. Finally I have set the viewgroup as contentview();

```
    sTabHost = new TabHost(context,null);
    sTabHost.setLayoutParams(
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));


    TabWidget tabWidget = new TabWidget(context);
    tabWidget.setId(android.R.id.tabs);
    sTabHost.addView(tabWidget, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
              LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 


    FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(context);
    frameLayout.setId(android.R.id.tabcontent);
    final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int paddingtop = (int) (64 * scale + 0.5f);
    frameLayout.setPadding(0, paddingtop, 0, 0);
    sTabHost.addView(frameLayout, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
              LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));         

    sTabHost.setup();
```

Then I have added the tab items like the below.

```
 public void addTabItem(final String url, String tabTitle, Drawable tabIcon)
{    
    TabSpec ts1 = sTabHost.newTabSpec(tabTitle); 
    if(tabTitle.equals(""))
    {
        int childcount=sTabHost.getChildCount();
        tabTitle="Tab" + String.valueOf(childcount+1);          
    }
    if(tabIcon==null)
        ts1.setIndicator(tabTitle);
    else
        ts1.setIndicator(tabTitle,tabIcon);        
    ts1.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory(){
         public View createTabContent(String tag)
         {               
                LinearLayout panel = new LinearLayout(sActiveContext);
                panel.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                panel.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                FrameLayout layout=new FrameLayout();
                    // Here I am creating the webview loaded with the url within the layout and placed into the above FrameLayout.                  
                panel.addView(layout);
                return panel;
         }  
    }); 
    sTabHost.addTab(ts1);
    sTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
  }
```

Now, how can I achieve this in actionbar like the image I have added.?

I have created the Action Bar with tabs like the below code.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    Tab tabA = actionBar.newTab();
    tabA.setText("Tab A");
    tabA.setTabListener(new TabListener<MyFragmentA>(this, "Tag A", MyFragmentA.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tabA);
}
```

The TabListener class is as below.

```
public static class TabListener<T extends Fragment> 
    implements ActionBar.TabListener{

    private final Activity myActivity;
    private final String myTag;
    private final Class<T> myClass;

    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> cls) {
        myActivity = activity;
        myTag = tag;
        myClass = cls;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        Fragment myFragment = myActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(myTag);

        // Check if the fragment is already initialized
        if (myFragment == null) {
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            myFragment = Fragment.instantiate(myActivity, myClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, myFragment, myTag);
        } else {
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            ft.show(myFragment);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        Fragment myFragment = myActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(myTag);

        if (myFragment != null) {
            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
            ft.hide(myFragment);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

The Fragment class is as below.

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_c, container, false);

    WebView webview = (WebView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false); 
    webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);   
    webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true); 
    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true); 
    webview.loadUrl("http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/");

    return myFragmentView;
}

public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {        
    /* (non-Java doc)
     * @see android.webkit.WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String)
     */


    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.endsWith(".mp4")) 
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "video/*");

            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        } 
        else {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    }
}
```

In the above implementation, I have created the layout and separate fragment class. Instead of creating like this how can I achieve this without creating the xml layout and separate fragment class. That is like the code i have posted for TabHost tab bar.

EDIT 3: I have created the action bar and tab items like the below code.

```
 public void addTabBar(Context context)
{       
    sActiveContext=context;
    sActionBar = getActionBar();
    sActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
}

public void addTabItem(final String url, String tabTitle)
{   
    Tab tab = sActionBar.newTab();
    if(tabTitle.equals(""))
    {
        int childcount=sActionBar.getTabCount();
        tabTitle="Tab" + String.valueOf(childcount+1);          
    }
    tab.setText(tabTitle);
     //Here I need to create the Layout with the webview and loaded into the created tab.
    tab.setTabListener(this);
    sActionBar.addTab(tab);
}
```

How can I achieve to load the webview with the given url to the specific tab.?

Comment: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/10/08/dynamically-adding-removing-toggling-removing-actionbar-tabs-android-part-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for Edit 3:-
Try this,

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class Sample extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener{
    private ActionBar mActionBar=null;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList=null;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout=null;
    private WebView webView=null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        linearLayout=new LinearLayout(this);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); 
        setContentView(linearLayout);
        mActionBar=getActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
            webView=new WebView(this);
        linearLayout.addView(webView);
        arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
        addTab(0,"https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://121.242.120.82:8090/iSmartDM/DC/KIMS_Hospital_28/KIMS_hospital_Default_29" +
                    "/Physician_2_37/DOC/stamos-5644-00@gs138a-[01062006]-[160859]-[ds4000]-[].rtf");
        addTab(1,"https://www.google.co.in");
        addTab(2,"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15964641/tab-bar-app-in-android-4-0/16009038?noredirect=1#comment22832140_16009038");
    }
    private void addTab(int position,String URL)
    {
mActionBar.addTab(mActionBar.newTab().setTag("tab"+String.valueOf(position)).
                    setText("Tab "+String.valueOf(position)).setTabListener(this));
            arrayList.add(URL);
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
                    if(tab.getPosition()==i)
                    {
                        webView.loadUrl(arrayList.get(i));
                        System.out.println(arrayList.get(i));
                        break;
                    }
                }
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            //if(webView!=null)
                //linearLayout.removeView(webView);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response Sino. If I am using the above code. I am restricted to create only the three tabs. If I am implement dynamically and covert the source as runnable JAR. Then I am able to call the addTab() by passing the title and url,and can create dynamically so many tabs. Could you please give some suggestions.?

Comment: Thanks a lot Sino. If I am getting the webview inside the linearlayout like,LinearLayout panel = new LinearLayout(sActiveContext);               panel.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
panel.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);              CustomWebView webview=new CustomWebView(sActiveContext);                 FrameLayout layout=webview.createwebview();  //I have created webview with some customized options.               webview.initwebview(url);               panel.addView(layout);return panel; Then how can I add this as content of tab

Comment: No need of the webview and settings. I am having the customized webview inside the linearlayout. If I am calling initwebview() method, I got the webview in the panel by add the layout. panel.addView(layout). My question is how can I add the linearlayout to the content of the specific tab.

Comment: If I am creating the application with single page means I have called the some other method for creating the webview, If It is tab bar application then I have called some set of methods to create webview. It's an ordinary webview inside the FrameLayout. I can call the method to retreive my custom webview anywhere.

Comment: I have called createTabContent() method, which creates the webview inside the linearlayout and returns the View. How can I load this view as content of the specific tab. This is what exactly I needed.

Comment: createTabContent() is only related to tab host and tab spec, so that has problem to implement on action bar tab.

Comment: Yes, that's related to tabhost I am just specify the name. If I am having the view with webview inside the linearlayout. How can I load this View as the content of the specific tab? This is what i needed.

Comment: This answer is the solution for your problem.When tabs on action bar can only focused on intermediate actions, that is not directly connected with the view/content. Action bar is mainly looks on fragment transactions, but also perform this type of actions. So you can change your code in to this way or use fragments.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If I am using the fragment transcations means, "tabA.setTabListener(new TabListener<MyFragmentA>(this, "Tag A", MyFragmentA.class));" is this the only way?. Or some other way is there for using the fragments. Because I am creating the tab item dynamically. How can I create the fragments dynamically?

Comment: In the above code, switching from one tab to another tab, the tab is recreated every time. How to prevent from re-creating the tab.?

Comment: tab is not recreated, but their view/content recreated/added on the basis of tab changing. If tab is unselected, that web view is removed from view group/linear layout. Now I edited that for to remove re-adding of web view...

Comment: Yes, the content of the tab is re-created. But the above code is not fixed the tab content re-creating issue. Can you please give some suggestion.?

Comment: I have loaded the custom webview into the corresponding tab by adding the panel to the linearlayout as per you code. In tabhost getCurrentWebView() is the method to get the webview. But unfortunately there is no method like that in the action bar tabs. How can I get the currentWebview loaded in the current selected tab?

Comment: Just use an ArrayList<WebView> arrayList=null, that is declared on out side of all functions, then intialize that ,and add each webview into that Array List with their postion. When you want to get that then, arrayList.get(getActionBar().getSelectedTab().getPosition());

Comment: Yes, I got the current webview. Thanks Sino. The tab content is re-created always on tab select. How can I fix this issue.?

Comment: Hi Sino, the content of the tab is re-created always. Could you please give some suggestions.?

Comment: Are you remove the 'CustomWebView' or clear linear layout after onTabUnSelected()?. The only way to handle this problem is using fragments for each tab transaction. Fragments can itself save their view on each time(when handle fragment transaction correctly).

Comment: I am not clearing anything. Yes, fragments have their own way to save the state. But how can I dynamically create fragment for each tab.

Comment: Is any other use for Linear Layout?, why you use CustomWebView? and What is structure for view(which based on tab change)?

Comment: There is no other use of the linear layout. The customized webview is used,because insteady of using the xml layouts, I can create instance of the webview and load the url directly. I can convert this customized webview as jar and used in many applications. I have posted the full code in "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028911/menu-in-action-bar-android/16030757?noredirect=1#comment22872361_16030757" this link. In onTabUnselected() method, I'm doing anything.

Comment: I have face the issue of getting the webview. That's If I am selecting the tab1 and tab3, adding webview in the arraylist without the second index(tab2), the application will be crashed.

Comment: Hi Sino, I am not able to create the fragment dynamically for the specific tab. Could you please help me.?

Comment: Hi Sino How to set action bar tabs bottom of screen

Answer (score 3):

**Action Bar with Fragments**

Try this, this works fine..

In manifest file,

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"/>
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
            android:name="packageName.ActionBarFragmentActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
<!--change  packageName -->
```

ActionBarFragmentActivity.java

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class ActionBarFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener{
    private ActionBar actionBar=null;
    private Fragment1 fragment1=null;
    private Fragment2 fragment2=null;
    private Fragment3 fragment3=null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
        actionBar=getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setTag("first").setText("First").setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setTag("second").setText("Second").setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setTag("third").setText("Third").setTabListener(this));

        fragment1=new Fragment1();
        fragment2=new Fragment2();
        fragment3=new Fragment3();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout,fragment1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if(tab.getPosition()==0)
        {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout,fragment1).commit();
            fragment1.onUpdateView();
        }
        else if(tab.getPosition()==1)
        {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout,fragment2).commit();
            fragment2.onUpdateView();
        }
        else if(tab.getPosition()==2)
        {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout,fragment3).commit();
            fragment3.onUpdateView();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

main_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</FrameLayout>
```

webview_layout.xml

```
<WebView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</WebView>
```

Fragment1.java

```
public class Fragment1 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{
    private WebView webView=null;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    } 
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview_layout, container, false);
          webView=(WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
          return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) 
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(bundle);
        onUpdateView();
    }
    public void onUpdateView()
    {
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://121.242.120.82:8090/iSmartDM/DC/KIMS_Hospital_28/KIMS_hospital_Default_29" +
                "/Physician_2_37/DOC/stamos-5644-00@gs138a-[01062006]-[160859]-[ds4000]-[].rtf");
    }
}
```

Fragmet2.java

```
public class Fragment2 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{
    private WebView webView=null;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    } 
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview_layout, container, false);
          webView=(WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
          return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) 
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(bundle);
    }
    public void onUpdateView()
    {
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.co.in/");
    }
}
```

Fragment3.java

```
public class Fragment3 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{
    private WebView webView=null;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    } 
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.webview_layout, container, false);
          webView=(WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
          return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) 
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(bundle);
    }
    public void onUpdateView()
    {
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/?gl=IN&tab=w1");
    }
}
```

Edited-------------"Dynamic Layouts"-------------------
Activity:-
    onCreate();

```
FrameLayout frameLayout=new FrameLayout(this);
    setContentView(frameLayout);
    frameLayout.setId(1111);
```

Fragment Transaction...

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(1111,fragment1).commit();
```

Fragment:-

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        webView=new WebView(getActivity());
        webView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        return webView;
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks Sino. I have posted also my code in my question. Could you please give some suggestions, to create all those things without using the xml layouts. How can I done all those things progrmatically without the xml layouts?

Comment: Hi, Can you please give me the suggestions on EDIT 3 in my question?

Comment: How to set tabs bottom of screen

Comment: @user2630955 - please read this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220428/placing-my-actionbar-at-the-bottom. Android isn't allow to add action bar at bottom, because default theme of android is tabs aligned at top. When you want this, you should follow another way like tab host, view pager indicator etc

Answer (score 0):

I think [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) is useful for you, for handle Action Bar. Also visit [this](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) for uses of Action Bar. Example and detailed description [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html) .

And the you can use Tab Host control for tabs inside of Fragment(Sub Tabs). When you need
sub tabs on a fragment, then use Layout for that Fragment as,

sub_tab_fragment.xml,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

And then inside of fragment,

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{   
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_tab_fragment, container, false);
     mTabHost=(TabHost)v.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
     return v;
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(bundle);
    mTabHost.setup();

    View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), "First");
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("First").setIndicator(tabview).setContent(R.id.realtabcontent));

    View tabview1 = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), "Second");
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Second").setIndicator(tabview1).setContent(R.id.realtabcontent));

    View tabview2 = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), "Third");
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Third").setIndicator(tabview2).setContent(R.id.realtabcontent));

    View tabview3 = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), "Fourth");
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Fourth").setIndicator(tabview3).setContent(R.id.realtabcontent));

    View tabview4 = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), "Fifth");
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Fifth").setIndicator(tabview4).setContent(R.id.realtabcontent));


  mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(mTabListener);
}
```

Then you will implement/handle contents of tabs(Same method used in Action Bar).

Edited-----addTabItem(final String url, String tabTitle, Drawable tabIcon)***********

```
public void addTabItem(final String url, String tabTitle, Drawable tabIcon)
{    
    WebView webView=null;
    TabSpec ts1 = sTabHost.newTabSpec(tabTitle); 
    if(tabTitle.equals(""))
    {
        int childcount=sTabHost.getChildCount();
        tabTitle="Tab" + String.valueOf(childcount+1);          
    }
    if(tabIcon==null)
        ts1.setIndicator(tabTitle);
    else
        ts1.setIndicator(tabTitle,tabIcon);        
    ts1.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory(){
         public View createTabContent(String tag)
         {               
               webView=new WebView(sActiveContext);
           webView.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                return webView;
         }  
    }); 
    sTabHost.addTab(ts1);
    sTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://121.242.120.82:8090/iSmartDM/DC/KIMS_Hospital_28/KIMS_hospital_Default_29" +
                "/Physician_2_37/DOC/stamos-5644-00@gs138a-[01062006]-[160859]-[ds4000]-[].rtf");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have already created the tab using the TabWidget and TabHost which was deprecated. Meanwhile we can use those functionalities. But I need the look and feel of the Android 4.0. How can I achieve it.? In the same time I need to load seperate  webview into the created tabs. I need to achieve same as in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

Comment: Hi, See my EDIT 2. I have added the code for creating the tab bar using the tabhost. How can I achieve it in actionbar.?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.i have already created like this and loaded the webview, which appears like tab bar in version 2.2. I need to change these appearance in android version 4.0. Could you pls help me.?

Comment: Are you looking for customizing action bar or to load contents in web view?

Comment: creating tab in action bar and to load webviews in created tabs.

Comment: Fragment is good concept for split activity in to multiple forms, and that have lot of new idea. This is good concept to create action bar in an activity

Comment: Are you visit 3 URLs on first paragraph of this answer. There contain all concept and idea about your problem..

Comment: First you try with that, if any problem you may ask to me.

Comment: Just now tried the sample. Created 5 tabs in the ActionBar. I have created the layout with webview. But in the webview css is not loaded.

Comment: I have created the sample with five tab bars in ActionBar and loaded different urls. Now, how can I achieve this in dynamically. That is like setting the content of the tab bar created using the TabHost and TabWidget. ts1.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory(){
             public View createTabContent(String tag)
             {              
              //Creating panel and loaded the webview. Like in my post
             }  
        });