# how to create menu bar at bottom of the activity using 4.0.3 SDK

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, menu, contextmenu, submenu

I am creating a menu in 4.0.3, according to documentation it always shows menu bar at the top of my activity but i want to show it at the bottom of my activity like that.How can i achieve this?

[image: i want to create a menu that will show at the bottom of my Main activity.]

Currently i am using the following code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}}
```

menue.xlm

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


<item
    android:id="@+id/weather"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:title="weather"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/second"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="Home"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/java"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="Java"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/android"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="Android"/>
</menu>
```

Mainfest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.bottom.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and it showing the following output.
[image]

Comment: you are using a tablet emulator. I am going to provide a solution soon but not sure it will work properly on the big screens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as i know there is no option to move the `ActionBar` entirely to the bottom. But still it is possible to display few items at the bottom. for that you need to do this:

- Just add `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` to your `activity` tag in the`AndroidManifest.xml` like this...

  `<activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">`

You can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220428/placing-my-actionbar-at-the-bottom)

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: its not working i have used it also but its not working.