# Android: how to replace the three dots in the TOOLBAR menu (not the action bar)

Tags: android, toolbar

How to replace the three dots that appear in the Toolbar by an image.

Is that even possible?

Comment: Possible [clone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26300480/3422245)

Comment: Is it so hard to google before asking? https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=replace+three+dots+in+toolbar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change three dots button on android to other button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267758/how-to-change-three-dots-button-on-android-to-other-button)

Comment: I already did read the question twice is not that hard... @an_droid_dev the results give the answer for the action bar not the toolbar. the internet gives the answer for the action bar not the toolbar... Ben P give the good answer. lol

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The "three dots" you see is called the "overflow icon", which is a configurable part of `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`.

In Java, call:

```
Drawable d = /* your drawable here */;
toolbar.setOverflowIcon(d);
```

Documentation here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html#setOverflowIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)

Comment: Thanks buddy. that was fast

Answer (score 1):

I have done that replaced 3 dots with rate app icon for my app. Change item in main_menu.xml like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/rateapp_bn"
        android:title="Rate App"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_stars_black_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. 
The three dots are appearing because you have more menu items that the ones that fit in your toolbar.

However you can do the following.

1. In the menu resource change `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"` by `app:showAsAction="always"`, that should show the icon whenever possible but it is not recommended.
2. Use the above configuration to show only the icons you need
3. Split your actionbar/toolbar so you can show some icons in the top section and some other in the bottom section. You can read more regarding this approach in the following links: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546160/how-to-enable-split-action-bar), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220428/placing-my-actionbar-at-the-bottom) and [here](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/index.html#SplitBar).

Hope it helps!